# Ubuntu Disks says : disk is likely to fail soon

Tags: hard-drive

I have a problem that every time I log into my Ubuntu 18 I see, the notification says: "this is likely to fail soon".

Thus I installed a software named `smartmontools` , and here is it's log (the smartmontools output) :

[image: the smartmontools output]

Now can someone please tell me what is the problem ? is it serious ? should I return it to where I bought it from in the first place ??

Thanks beforehand

Comment: Yep, it is serious, return if possible.

Comment: Should backup any important data soon, use another drive/USB.  Might be a bad drive.

Comment: FYI:  Rather than install & run `smartctl` from hdd/ssd, you should have booted a live media (eg. Ubuntu install media) and run it from there.  That way you're not using the disk (SMART data is read from chips) and can assess the plan ahead without using some of the life that still exists in a suspected drive. If the drive is failing, you've then more time to get any valuable data off (instead of using it installing software & running tests in planning, if done from 'live' media the drive isn't touched during this evaluation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at least you can see "Relocated sectors count" in the SMART report.
That's not good. It says that disk is already using relocation blocks
and so there are already bad blocks on your disk. After some time there
will be no more free relocation blocks and relocation won't be possible..
Then UNC errors appears and your disk will be dead.

Make backup asap and switch to new one if you like your data :)

> Reallocated Sectors Count S.M.A.R.T. parameter indicates the count of
>   reallocated sectors (512 bytes). When the hard drive finds a
>   read/write/verification error, it marks this sector as "reallocated"
>   and transfers data to a special reserved area (spare area). This
>   process is also known as remapping and "reallocated" sectors are
>   called remaps. This is why, on a modern hard disks, you will not see
>   "bad blocks" while testing the surface - all bad blocks are hidden in
>   reallocated sectors.